# After groupingBy convert list of objects from Type A to Type B

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

```
Map<Integer,List<ItemTypeA>> list = data.stream().collect(groupingBy(ItemTypeA::getId));
```

I have a function that converts ItemTypeA to ItemTypeB .

```
public ItemTypeB convert (ItemTypeA);
```

How can I use that after `groupingBy` here so that that the end result is as shown below.

```
Map<Integer,List<ItemTypeB>> map = data.stream().collect(groupingBy(ItemTypeA::getId),
```

How to invoke function to convert `ItemTypeA` to `ItemTypeB`?;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.mapping`:

```
Map<Integer,List<ItemTypeB>> output = 
    data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ItemTypeA::getId,
                 Collectors.mapping(a->convert(a),
                                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to apply some filter as well after convert(a) and then collect it to a List() ?

Comment: @aquitted-mind I don't think so. Can't you perform the filtering prior to the `collect` step?

Comment: Yeah, can't since it is to be applied on the converted object. But I think you have answered my original question.

Comment: @aquitted-mind that would require Java 9: [`Collectors.groupingBy(ItemTypeA::getId, Collectors.mapping(a -> convert(a), Collectors.filtering(b -> criteria, Collectors.toList())))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-). Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48276796/2711488) for a Java 8 compatible back-port.