# How to easily implement conditional count in groupby using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

**I have the following data(A class structure):**

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "enable": true
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "enable": false
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "enable": false
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "enable": false
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "enable": false
  }
]
```

**How can I replace the complex code below with a simple steam:**

```
List<A> list = xxxxx;
Map<String, Integer> aCountMap = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(item -> {
    Integer count = aCountMap.get(item.getName());
    if (Objects.isNull(count)) {
        aCountMap.put(item.getName(), 0);
    }
    if (item.isEnable()) {
        aCountMap.put(item.getName(), ++count);
    }
});
```

**The correct result is as follows:**

```
{"a":1}
{"b":0}
{"c":0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might simply be counting the objects filtered by a condition:

```
Map<String, Long> aCountMap = list.stream()
        .filter(A::isEnable)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getName, Collectors.counting()));
```

But since you are looking for the `0` count as well, `Collectors.filtering` with Java-9+ provides you the implementation such as :

```
Map<String, Long> aCountMap = List.of().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getName,
                Collectors.filtering(A::isEnable,
                        Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: Is there a similar approach for Java 8？

Comment: @赵彬杰 [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48276796/1746118) shares an approach of how you can create a static method in Java-8 as well.