# Split Java-8 Stream result into Success and Failure list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've a List of Foo, where on each Foo I apply a processor method to get `ValidItem`.
If there is an error in processing, then I returned `ErrorItem`.

Now How to process this by Java 8 streams to get the result in form of 2 different lists

```
List<Foo> FooList = someList....;

class ValidItem extend Item{......}
class ErrorItem extend Item{......}


Item processItem(Foo  foo){
   return either an object of ValidItem or ErrorItem;
}
```

I believe I can do this

```
 Map<Class,List<Item>> itemsMap =
    FooList
    .stream()
    .map(processItem)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
```

But as `List<Parent>` IS NOT a `List<Child>` so I can't typecast the map result into `List<ValidItem>`
In reality `ErrorItem` and `ValidItem` are two completely different class not related at all, just for the sake of this steam processing and processItem method I kept them in same hierarchy by extending a marker Item class,.

and in many other Places in code, I cant/shouldn't refer ValidItem as Item , as It give an idea that it can be an ErroItem too.

Is there a proper way of doing it with streams, where at the end I get 2 lists. and ErrorItem and 
ValidItem are not extending same Item class ?

***############## Update ##############***
As I said ValidItem and ErrorItem shouldn't be same, so I changed the signature of process method and passed it a list. 
I know this is not how Stream shold be used. Let me know if you have better way

```
    List<Foo> FooList = someList....;

    class ValidItem {......}
    class InvalidFoo{......}


    ValidItem processFoo(Foo  foo, List<InvalidFoo> foolist){
      Do some processing on foo.
       either return  new ValidItem ();
         OR 
         fooList.add(new InvalidFoo()) , and then return null;
    }

List<InvalidFoo> invalidFooList = new ArrayList();
     List<ValidItem> validItem =
        fooList
        .stream()
        .map(e->processItem(e,invalidFooList))
        .filter(Objects::notNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

now I have both invalid and valid list, but this doesn't look like a clean stream code.

Comment: you shouldn't base your entity design around stream processing, rather use streams on elements as designed. that said, with a type attribute in both the classes to distinguish them, you can then group by that attribute and later cast to specific instance.

Comment: Agree with your design comment. But these aren't business entities.
Just for the sake of question, I posted this.... basically, I'm doing file processing. These are  processing result items for each line.....based upon resulting `List<ValidItems>`  I will create entity to persist and will send `List<ErrorItems>` back to UI....... I also felt that I shouldn't keep them in same object hierarchy, thus asked  question. Suggestion you provided is not solving the problem I asked, I don't have problem in grouping them. My problem is How to have list of 2 different classes returned by streams collect

Comment: You're reading a file and from each line of the file you create either an `ErrorItem` or a `ValidItem` and you want to create two separate lists, namely `List<ErrorItem>` and `LIst<ValidItem>`. Is that correct? Is the file a text file?

Comment: @Arba Its CSV , but Yeah, It can be considered text too... Thing is,  `ErrorItem` is not at all similar to `ValidItem`... In `ErrorItem` I'm just putting the `errorMessage`, `errorReason`,  `fieldname` (if its a field error) and complete `originalline`,  so user can refer,  Whereas  `ValidItem` is not exactly but very close to my Business Entity.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post some sample lines from your CSV including valid lines and error lines and indicate what results you require from such sample data?

Comment: @Abra, thats actually not the problem statement, You can consider the problem in as its defined, I'm only looking for stream based solution where I need to return list of 2 different Classes by one processing(map) method.

Answer (score 5):

With recent Java versions, you can use

- for the `Item processItem(Foo foo)` method returning either `ValidItem` or `ErrorItem`:

  ```
  Map.Entry<List<ValidItem>, List<ErrorItem>> collected = fooList.stream()
    .map(this::processItem)
    .collect(teeing(
      flatMapping(x -> x instanceof ValidItem? Stream.of((ValidItem)x):null, toList()),
      flatMapping(x -> x instanceof ErrorItem? Stream.of((ErrorItem)x):null, toList()),
      AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::new
    ));

  List<ValidItem> valid = collected.getKey();
  List<ErrorItem> invalid = collected.getValue();
  ```
- for the `ValidItem processFoo(Foo foo, List<InvalidFoo> foolist)`:

  ```
  Map.Entry<List<ValidItem>, List<InvalidFoo>> collected = fooList.stream()
      .map(foo -> {
          List<InvalidFoo> invalid = new ArrayList<>(1);
          ValidItem vi = processFoo(foo, invalid);
          return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
              vi == null? Collections.<ValidItem>emptyList():
                          Collections.singletonList(vi),
              invalid);
      })
      .collect(teeing(
          flatMapping(e -> e.getKey().stream(), toList()),
          flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), toList()),
          AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::new
      ));

  List<ValidItem> valid = collected.getKey();
  List<InvalidFoo> invalid = collected.getValue();
  ```

The `flatMapping` collector has been introduced in Java 9.
In this specific case, instead of

```
flatMapping(x -> x instanceof ValidItem? Stream.of((ValidItem)x): null, toList())
```

you can also use

```
filtering(x -> x instanceof ValidItem, mapping(x -> (ValidItem)x, toList()))
```

but each variant requires Java 9, as `filtering` also does not exist in Java 8. The `teeing` collector even requires Java 12.

However, these collectors are not hard to implement.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488) contains a Java 8 compatible version of the `flatMapping` collector at the end. If you want to use the alternative with `filtering` and `mapping`, you can find a Java 8 compatible version of `filtering` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48276796/2711488). Finally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030899/2711488) contains a Java 8 compatible variant of the `teeing` collector.

When you add these collectors to your codebase, the solutions at the beginning of this answer work under Java 8 and will being easily adaptable to future versions. Assuming an `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;` in your source file, you only have to remove the backports of these methods, to switch to the standard JDK versions.

---

It would be better if `processItem` returned an `Either` or `Pair` type instead of the two variants addressed above. If you don’t want to use 3rd party libraries, you can use a `Map.Entry` instance as a “poor man’s pair type”.

Having a method signature like

```
/** Returns an entry with either, key or value, being {@code null} */
Map.Entry<ValidItem,InvalidFoo> processItem(Foo foo){
```

which could be implemented by returning an instance of `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`,

a JDK 9+ solution could look like

```
Map.Entry<List<ValidItem>, List<InvalidFoo>> collected = fooList.stream()
    .map(this::processItem)
    .collect(teeing(
        flatMapping(e -> Stream.ofNullable(e.getKey()), toList()),
        flatMapping(e -> Stream.ofNullable(e.getValue()), toList()),
        AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::new
    ));
```

and Java 8 compatible (when using the linked collector backports) versions:

```
Map.Entry<List<ValidItem>, List<InvalidFoo>> collected = fooList.stream()
    .map(this::processItem)
    .collect(teeing(
        flatMapping(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey()).filter(Objects::nonNull), toList()),
        flatMapping(e -> Stream.of(e.getValue()).filter(Objects::nonNull), toList()),
        AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::new
    ));
```

or

```
Map.Entry<List<ValidItem>, List<InvalidFoo>> collected = fooList.stream()
    .map(this::processItem)
    .collect(teeing(
        mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, filtering(Objects::nonNull, toList())),
        mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, filtering(Objects::nonNull, toList())),
        AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::new
    ));
```

Comment: Just an opinion, for someone on Java-12+, `Map.Entry<List<ValidItem>, List<ErrorItem>> collected` could not be as important and they can make use of `var collected`.

Comment: @Naman I’m not sure whether the result type of the `collect` operation is so obvious to the reader that writing `var` instead would be an improvement in this specific case. I’m not even sure whether type inference would do its job then. Maybe a recent version using a `record` would improve this, but I’d wait for the deconstruction language feature, to directly get two variables of type `List`, before making a change…

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> FooList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
            FooList.add(new Foo(i+""));
        }
        Map<Class,List<Item>> itemsMap =
                FooList
                        .stream()
                        .map(Main::processItem)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
        List<ValidItem> validItems = itemsMap.get(ValidItem.class).stream().map((o -> (ValidItem)o)).collect(Collectors.toList());



    }
    public static Item processItem(Foo  foo){
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(Integer.parseInt(foo.name) % 2== 0){
            return new ValidItem(foo.name);
        }else{
            return new ErrorItem(foo.name);
        }
    }
    static class ValidItem extends Item{
        public ValidItem(String name) {
            super("valid: " + name);
        }
    }
    static class ErrorItem extends Item{
        public ErrorItem(String name) {
            super("error: "+name);
        }
    }
    public static class Item {
        private String name;

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

I suggest this solution.

Comment: Wont work, compilation error, `Cannot cast from Item to ValidItem`  error at second line

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I uploaded my whole application. If you cannot cast, u initiate Item class not ValidItem or ErrorItem

Comment: You are missing Foo definition. but i checked. your code is compiles..I upvoted  but not accepted as answer, as if you read my last 2 lines (now those are lines before update) i asked something else, i said that i did this hierarchy, but this was not right... and i was looking for that solution....but great effort. i upvoted your answer...marked as useful..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vavr library.

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", ",", "1", "0");
final List<Either<ErrorItem, ValidItem>> eithers = list.stream()
                .map(MainClass::processData)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
final List<ValidItem> validItems = eithers.stream()
                .filter(Either::isRight)
                .map(Either::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
final List<ErrorItem> errorItems = eithers.stream()
                .filter(Either::isLeft)
                .map(Either::getLeft)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

...

private static Either<ErrorItem,ValidItem> processData(String data){
        if(data.equals("1")){
            return Either.right(new ValidItem());
        }
        return Either.left(new ErrorItem());
}
```